# What is the probability of drawing the last red ball in the fourth draw?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There are 8 Blue(B) and 2 Red(R) balls in a bag. Each time one ball is drawn and replaced by Blue one. What is the probability of drawing the last red ball in the fourth draw ?

---

I made 3 cases :

A). BBRR = $(\frac{8}{10})^2\cdot \frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{10}$

B). RBBR = $\frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{10}$

C). BRBR = $\frac{8}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{9}{10}.\frac{1}{10}$

Hence, Total Probability :-

=> $P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$

=> ${ (\frac{8}{10})^2\cdot \frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{10} }$ + $\frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{10}$ + $\frac{8}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{10}$

---

Have I made it Right ?

Comment: Good logic, calculation seems sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to generalize a little bit

Assuming $ N $ = Total Number of draws

Notes:

- Probability to draw the first red ball is always 2/10
- Probability to draw the second red ball is always 1/10

If $ i \in (1,N-1) $ is the draw you get the first red ball at, then

- Probability to draw a blue ball for $ 1 \le j < i $ is 8/10
- Probability to draw a blue ball for $ i < j < N-1 $ is 9/10

Then you can define a function for computing the probability of a specific scenario

$$ P(i;N) = \left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^{i-1} \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{N-1-i} \left(\frac{2}{10}\right) \left(\frac{1}{10}\right) $$

Then you can compute the sum over all the possible scenario

$$ P_{final} = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1}P(i;N) $$